# How can I locate my extension directory?

Tags: extension, civix

This question surprised me a bit - but I have no clue about where to locate my extension directory!!

Is there a simple way to reliably locate it (either programatically or via the UI)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find your extension directory by going to **Administer menu » System Settings » Directories** and checking the value for the "Extensions" directory.  If there's a token like [civicrm.root], you can determine its value [with this technique](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/16611/12).

Answer (score 3):

In PHP it looks like this is what I need:

```
return (new CRM_Extension_System())->getDefaultContainer()->baseDir;
```

So in `bash` I can use `cv`:

```
cv ev 'return (new CRM_Extension_System())->getDefaultContainer()->baseDir'
```

or better still, as pointed out be Tim:

```
cv ev 'return CRM_Core_Config::singleton()->extensionsDir'
```

which means this one liner will take you to the directory:

```
cd `cv ev 'return CRM_Core_Config::singleton()->extensionsDir;' --out=pretty`
```

Comment: I happened to find this way as the simplest but if there is a non-programtic way that would be awesome!

Comment: (1) That's a clever way. FWIW, the traditional PHP snippet find the default container is `CRM_Core_Config::singleton()->extensionsDir;`. (2) Coincidentally, I've been mulling a form of this problem in https://github.com/civicrm/cv/pull/14