# How do I install an extension directly from git?

Tags: extension, developer

Now that I have [found my extension directory](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16788/where-is-my-extension-directory), is installing an experimental (or developmental) extension as simple as cloning it into there? eg:

```
# find extension directory
DIR=$(cv ev --out=pretty 'return (new CRM_Extension_System())->getDefaultContainer()->baseDir')
# change to extension directory
cd $DIR
# clone repo
git clone git@github.com:civicrm/api4.git
# flush cache
cv flush
# enable 
cv ext:enable api4
```

(obviously some `git remote` voodoo required still but just wanting to confirm that this is the basics)

Comment: That all looks correct to me. Is it not working?

Comment: yes it's working - but I couldn't find process documented anywhere so wanted to confirm before adding to the dev guide!

Comment: Installing an extension manually is mentioned here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions#Extensions-Installinganewextension

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's all you need to do!  In my experience, flushing the cache is unnecessary though.